# HDMI/DVI capture/recording hardware?

Tags: hardware, video-recording

Does anyone know a Framegrabber / capture device that works for all HMDI, VGA, DVI, SDI ?

Comment: So you're looking for a capture card / device with HDMI/DVI/etc. inputs?  I made an edit-suggestion to the question that should help make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Foresight Imaging cards support all types at HD and up to 60/sec